# Change timezone on macOS Docker xhyve virtual machine

Tags: macos, docker, timezone

How can I change the timezone in the xhyve virtual machine of macOS Docker?

My primary problem is that Docker has set UTC as the default timezone in the macOS VM. My macOS runs with CET for example. So I have a wrong time display in all my Docker containers per default.

I use Docker Desktop Community v2.0.0.3.

Comment: Hi, and welcome!  As written, your question is off topic for Stack Overflow.  You may have better luck on other Stack Exchange sites, such as [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).  Alternatively, you could edit your question to better fit the [Stack Overflow on-topic guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). For example, you could describe the code that you are using within the Docker container that needs a particular system local time zone to be set (since [that is generally an anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30897258/634824)).

Comment: @Matt Johnson, thank you for your answer and clues. The anti-pattern hint was very good. I will reconsider my approach.